# GeoServer REST WorkspacesAPI.postWorkspaces call by a Swagger client fails: "CannotResolveClassException: name". Unexpected JSON content received

Tags: json, xml, geoserver-rest-api

Using *GeoServer* `2.18.2` REST API by a *Swagger* *Java* client generated from `workspaces.yaml` (taken from [documentation page](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/workspaces.yaml)), I attempted to create a workspace through this small test code, under *Spring boot* :

```java
public class ConfigurateurIT {
   /** Créer un workspace. */
   @Test
   @DisplayName("Créer un workspace")
   public void createWorkspace() {
      Workspace workspace = new Workspace();
      workspace.setName("ecoemploi");
      
      WorkspacesApi workspacesApi = new WorkspacesApi(apiClient());
      String response = workspacesApi.postWorkspaces(workspace, true);
      
      assertEquals("200", response, "Le workspace n'a pas été créé.");
   }
   
   /**
    * S'authentifier sur le geoserver de test.
    * @return Api Client.
    */
   private ApiClient apiClient() {
      ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
      apiClient.setBasePath("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest");
      
      HttpBasicAuth basicAuthentication = (HttpBasicAuth)apiClient.getAuthentication("basic");
      basicAuthentication.setUsername("admin");
      basicAuthentication.setPassword("geoserver");
      return apiClient;
   }
}
```

but it fails. Client side, the logs are :

```
09:26:00.108 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - HTTP POST http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces?default=true
09:26:00.114 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
09:26:00.146 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [class Workspace {
    name: ecoemploi
}] as "application/json"
09:26:00.226 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

And server side :

```
29 janv. 09:26:00 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - name
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: name
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
[...]
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:206)
[...]
org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
[...]
```

Entering a debug session, client side, I go to the step where Swagger is about to invoke the REST API :

[image]

The `invokeAPI` method leads it here :

[image]

(headers content is :
`[Accept:"application/json", Content-Type:"application/json", Authorization:"Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy", User-Agent:"Java-SDK"]`
)

And the `exchange` method of `restTemplate` is using this content at the time it is about send its data to *Geoserver* :

[image]

Am I lacking a part of REST method call preparation for `postWorkspaces`? Such as, for example, a first call to another method of the *GeoServer* REST API that should be done first to initialize the session?

The request seems to carry the due json content, and the request is created by *Swagger*, following `yaml` file indications, as I don't intervene in this process.

---

Geoserver logs at dev level :

```
29 janv. 15:09:55 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /home/marc/geoserver-2.18.2-bin/data_dir/gwc-layers
29 janv. 15:09:55 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 329us for /home/marc/geoserver-2.18.2-bin/data_dir/gwc-layers
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces, QueryString: default=true'; against '/web/**'
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces, QueryString: default=true'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces, QueryString: default=true'; against '/'
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces, QueryString: default=true'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces, QueryString: default=true'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces, QueryString: default=true'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces, QueryString: default=true'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces, QueryString: default=true'; against '/rest/**'
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /rest/workspaces, QueryString: default=true with /rest/**
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache has no entry for basic, admin:bfa584f5598433a3c1fe16b00acc9c43
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.rememberme.GeoServerTokenBasedRememberMeServices] - Did not send remember-me cookie (principal did not set parameter '_spring_security_remember_me')
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.rememberme.GeoServerTokenBasedRememberMeServices] - Remember-me login not requested.
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache adding new entry for basic, admin:bfa584f5598433a3c1fe16b00acc9c43
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security] - Cache entries #: 0
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache added new entry for basic, admin:bfa584f5598433a3c1fe16b00acc9c43
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security] - Cache entries #: 1
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/rest/workspaces'; to: '/rest/workspaces'  and httpMethod= POST
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [GET]
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/rest/workspaces'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=false
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [POST, DELETE, PUT]
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/rest/workspaces'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=true
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - returning ADMIN
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 23 locking in mode WRITE
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 23 got the lock in mode WRITE
29 janv. 15:09:59 ERROR [org.geoserver.rest] - name
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: name
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at org.geoserver.config.util.SecureXStream$DetailedSecurityExceptionWrapper.realClass(SecureXStream.java:490)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:133)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1487)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1467)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1347)
    at org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister.load(XStreamPersister.java:665)
    at org.geoserver.rest.converters.XStreamJSONMessageConverter.readInternal(XStreamJSONMessageConverter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 23 locking in mode WRITE
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 23 releasing the lock in mode WRITE
29 janv. 15:09:59 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
29 janv. 15:10:00 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /home/marc/geoserver-2.18.2-bin/data_dir/gwc-layers
```

---

I made other attempts to isolate the problem better :

1. An XML call of the REST API in XML mode, like docs suggest is working well :
   `curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<workspace><name>acme</name></workspace>" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces`
2. A JSON call of the REST API, too :
   `curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type:text/json" -d "{workspace:{name:'acme'}}" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces`
3. Through it's `toString()` method, the `Workspace` class generated by *Swagger* is returning a `class Workspace { name: acme }` that *Geoserver* receives as `{ name: acme }` and creates the problem, because *Geoserver* code is customized and assumes that it will receive a `"workspace"` extra attribute, coming from "xml:" attribute, here :

```yaml
definitions:
  Workspace:
    title: Workspace
    xml:
      name: workspace
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
        description: name of the workspace
```

But this `xml:` attribute isn't a part of the [Openapi 2.0 definition for a schema](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#schemaObject), and *Swagger* generator won't create the customized json *Geoserver* wishes.

Comment: Can you please include the actual JSON being sent to GeoServer and the log file entry with the log level turned upto GEOTOOLS-DEV level,

Comment: @IanTurton for the JSON content send is, I think, the content of bufferedOutput you can see on the last image. I will try the geotools-dev level if I see how to set it.

Comment: pictures of text are no use to anyone, goto global menu of geoserver to set logging level

Comment: @IanTurton I've edited the post with them.